# hibernate session.persist(object) create more rows in database

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Helo,

I have method

```
public void createContest(Contest c) {      
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.persist(c);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    logger.info("Contest saved successfully!");
}
```

I call it in one place with one object but this method save the object Contest to the database 4x. What could be the problem?

Here is Contest class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Contest")
public class Contest implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="CONTEST_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 5, scale = 0)
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name="DATE_OF_EVENT")
private Date dateOfEvent;

@Column(name="REG_OPEN")
private Date regOpen;

@Column(name="REG_CLOSE")
private Date regClose;

@Column(name="REG_RESTRICTION")
private Boolean regRestriction;

@Column(name="CAPACITY")
private int capacity;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="upperContest")
private List<Contest> precontests;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="UPPER_CONTEST_ID")
private Contest upperContest;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="MANAGING", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CONTEST_ID")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")})
private List<Person> managers;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="contest")
private List<Team> teams;

public Contest(String name, Date dateOfEvent, Date regOpen,
        Date regClose, Boolean regRestriction) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dateOfEvent = dateOfEvent;
    this.regOpen = regOpen;
    this.regClose = regClose;
    this.regRestriction = regRestriction;

    this.precontests = new ArrayList<Contest>();
    this.managers = new ArrayList<Person>();
    this.teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Date getDateOfEvent() {
    return dateOfEvent;
}

public void setDateOfEvent(Date dateOfEvent) {
    this.dateOfEvent = dateOfEvent;
}

public Date getRegOpen() {
    return regOpen;
}
public void setRegOpen(Date regOpen) {
    this.regOpen = regOpen;
}   

public Date getRegClose() {
    return regClose;
}
public void setRegClose(Date regClose) {
    this.regClose = regClose;
}

public Boolean getRegRestriction() {
    return regRestriction;
}
public void setRegRestriction(Boolean regRestriction) {
    this.regRestriction = regRestriction;
}

public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}

public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

public Contest getUpperContest() {
    return upperContest;
}

public void setUpperContest(Contest c) {
    this.upperContest = c;
}

public List<Contest> getPrecontests() {
    return precontests;
}

public void addPrecontest(Contest e) {
    this.precontests.add(e);
} 

public void addManager(Person p){
    this.managers.add(p);
}

public void addTeam(Team t){
    this.teams.add(t);
}

public List<Person> getManagers(){
    return managers;
}
```

}

And now I have to add some text because of restrictions of stackoverflow. Such Cool. Very wow.

Comment: Also logger's info??

Comment: Can you post the code of `Contest`, and how you instantiate it (the code which calls `createContest()`). Are there any self-refernces?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the code where you instantiate `Contest` and populate its fields, but `upperContest` is probably the cause. You have `CascadeType.ALL` on the mapping, so you probably are persisting one contest which has a upper contest, thus actually persisting two instances because of cascade setting. Can't know for sure without that code.